# How to login and get a list of accounts from C#

Tags: api, webservices, account, c#

I am trying access the Salesforce API from an external application.  I've done the following:

1. I've gone to the API tab and generated the WSDL.
2. I then ran the .NET framework's WSDL tool to generate the C# file, which I then added to my C# project.
3. I then attempted to login in the following manner:

   SforceService binding = new SforceService();
   LoginResult result = sfs.login(uid, pwd);

I get an error on the `.login` method: `INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.`

Then I realized that we have single signon enabled on our environment, so that maybe the .login method is unnecesary.  So I proceeded without it.

```
SforceService binding = new SforceService();
var qResult = binding.query("SELECT Name FROM Account");
```

I got an error on the `.query` method: `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService`.

So I am lost at this point.  Is there something simple I am missing?

Comment: You might haven't set the production/sandbox setting accordingly? If you're trying to authenticate to a sandbox instance, make sure you edit the `Properties -> Settings.settings` file and change the URL from `https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/XX.X` to `https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/XX.X`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the wrong username, but there was actually more to it.  I had to reset session ID and server URL.

Here is the way to do it, so that others can benefit.

```
bool done = false;

var binding = new SforceService();
LoginResult result = binding.login("user@foo.bar", "password");

binding.Url = result.serverUrl;
// The line below is what I've missed
binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader {sessionId = result.sessionId};

var queryResults = binding.query("SELECT Name FROM Account");

if (queryResults.size > 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Logged-in user can see a total of " + queryResults.size + " accounts.");
    while (!done)
    {
        sObject[] records = queryResults.records;
        for (int i = 0; i < records.Length; ++i)
        {
            var con = (Account)records[i];
            Debug.WriteLine("Account " + (i + 1) + ": " + con.Name);
        }

        if (queryResults.done)
            done = true;
        else
            queryResults = binding.queryMore(queryResults.queryLocator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you always need to replace the session header, every time you authenticate it gives you a different one so you were probably using an expired session id. Please accept your own answer